# How to fix "Parsing Error" when adding the <motion.div /> element in React / Framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I started a new react app [create-react-app] and installed framer-motion. The app runs as expected until adding a framer motion element:

```js
export const HomePageTemplate = ({ home }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <motion.div animate={{ x: 50 }}>
        <h1>Hello Motion</h1>
      </motion.div>
    </div>

      <section className="home  section">
...
```

Relevant errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expirationTime' of undefined
```

```
C:/[my path]/node_modules/react-error-overlay/lib/index.js:2172 Warning: The <_default /> component appears to be a function component that returns a class instance. Change _default to a class that extends React.Component instead. If you can't use a class try assigning the prototype on the function as a workaround. `_default.prototype = React.Component.prototype`. Don't use an arrow function since it cannot be called with `new` by React.
```

```
C:/[my path]/node_modules/react-error->overlay/lib/index.js:2172 The above error occurred in the <Component> >component: 
in Component (created by ForwardRef(MotionComponent))
    in ForwardRef(MotionComponent) (at pages/index.js:18)
    in div (at pages/index.js:16)
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what the exact error is. In your code sample on line 3 there's an opening `<Fragment>` but later you close a `</div>` tag. When I test this in an app, I get this error: `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Fragment>`. Not sure how you can trigger the error with `expirationTime`?

Is it possible for you to share an isolated Code Sandbox? That would help!

Answer (score 0):

Is that the exact code from your app? It seems like you're missing the opening `<motion` part to create a framer motion element:

```
<h1>Hello Motion</h1>
<motion.div animate={{ x: 100 }} />
```

See this code sandbox for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-stackoverflow-wbmbe.

Are you familiar with React in general? The [tutorial in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) covers how to create elements.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I edited my question to include the <motion.div element. Based on your example, I needed to add the animate object first, not the <h1> or anything else. Thanks!

Comment: The code works in a new app, but when I wrap any element in my actual project, it fails. I'll update my question with more code.